# function to search value inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got the first(main) array as below,

```
$groceritems = array(
        "apple" => array(
                "price"=>"10",
                "origin"=>array("australia","belgium","USA","canada"),
                "breed"=>array("gala","fuji","Honeycrisp","washington"),),

        "orange" => array(
                "price"=>"10",
                "origin"=>array("australia","belgium","USA","canada"),
                "breed"=>array("gala","fuji","Honeycrisp","washington"),

        ),
);
foreach ($groceritems as $key => $value) {
    $origins = $value['origin'];
    $breeds= $value['breed'];

    foreach (array_combine($origins, $breeds) as $origin=>$breed) { 

echo $breed ." ".$key." from ". $origin ." price is RM ". $value['price'];

        echo "<br>";    

    }


}
```

second array as below,

```
$grocer= array(


"apple" => array( "country"=>"australia",
                  "newprice"=>"50",
                  "breed"=>"gala"),


"orange" => array("country"=>"belgium",
                  "newprice"=>"30",
                   "breed"=>"gala"),


);
```

i am able to loop the first array but how to replace the price of first array(while in foreach loop) to newprice with condition the category(orange/apple), country and breed matched second array?
like below result,

gala apple from australia price is RM 50

fuji apple from belgium price is RM 10

Honeycrisp apple from USA price is RM 10

washington apple from canada price is RM 10

gala orange from australia price is RM 10

fuji orange from belgium price is RM 10

Honeycrisp orange from USA price is RM 10

washington orange from canada price is RM 10

Answer (score 0):

To have the desired result, do the following

```
$groceritems = array(
    "apple" => array(
        "price"=>"10",
        "origin"=>array("australia","belgium","USA","canada"),
        "breed"=>array("gala","fuji","Honeycrisp","washington"),),

    "orange" => array(
        "price"=>"10",
        "origin"=>array("australia","belgium","USA","canada"),
        "breed"=>array("gala","fuji","Honeycrisp","washington"),

    ),
);

$grocer= array(
    "apple" => array( "country"=>"australia",
        "newprice"=>"50",
        "breed"=>"gala"),


    "orange" => array("country"=>"belgium",
        "newprice"=>"30",
        "breed"=>"gala"),
);

foreach ($groceritems as $key => $value) {
    $origins = $value['origin'];
    $breeds= $value['breed'];

    foreach (array_combine($origins, $breeds) as $origin=>$breed) {

        if(isset($grocer[$key]) && $origin == $grocer[$key]['country'] && $breed == $grocer[$key]['breed'] ){
            $price =  $grocer[$key]['newprice'];
        } else {
            $price = $value['price'];
        }

        echo $breed ." ".$key." from ". $origin ." price is RM ". $price;

        echo "<br>";

    }
}
```

Comment: it only allow to change single value for whole set of looping.
"apple" => array( "country"=>"australia",
                  "newprice"=>"50",
                  "breed"=>"gala"),
"apple" => array( "country"=>"australia",
                  "newprice"=>"50",
                  "breed"=>"fuji"),
when i type in new array, it wouldn't change as stated in second array. any solution? thanks in advance :)